# Memory management for classes like NSNumber, NSSet

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsnumber, nsautoreleasepool, nsset

These are classes and they declares pointers... to objects right?  You send methods to them like objects.
`NSNumber * myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: x];`

So why are they not released like so:
`[myNumber release];`

Thanks!

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By convention, class method initializers like the one you've shown create autoreleased instances, so you don't need to call `release` unless you `retain` them somehow.  However, the instance method initializers - like `initWithInteger:` in your case - return retained instances.  Those you would need to release yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There is a rule you should remember about memory management "NARC": When you use New Alloc Retain Copy you should release or autorelease object, otherwise you shouldn't.